# Метод редактирования сообщений editMessageText в Telegram боте

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot, google-apps-script

Есть следующий код, пробовал передавать разные параметры editMessageText методу но никак не работает.

```
function EditText(chatId, text, keyBoard) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "editMessageText",
      chat_id: String(chatId),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyBoard)
    }
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/', data);
}

if (contents.callback_query) {
    var id_callback = contents.callback_query.from.id;
    var data = contents.callback_query.data;
    var cb_firstName = contents.callback_query.from.first_name;

    if (data == 'links') 
    {
      sendText(id_callback,"Some text" ,keyBoard);
    } 

else if (contents.message) 
  {
    var id_message = contents.message.from.id;
    var id_text = contents.message.id;
    var text = contents.message.text; 
    var item = text.split("=");
    var firstName = contents.message.from.first_name;
    var userName = '@'+contents.message.from.username;

      sendText(id_message, "I want edit this message as it appears when bot starrts or someone send text",keyBoard)
    }
```

sendText метод такой же как и  EditText но его method: "sendMessage"
Может ко подскажет как можно редактировать предыдущее сообщение бота, а не каждый раз высылать новое.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function EditText(chatId, calmsgId, text, keyBoard) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "editMessageText",
      chat_id: String(chatId),
      message_id: calmsgId,
      text: text,
      parse_mode: "HTML",
      reply_markup: JSON.stringify(keyBoard)
    }
  };

  
 UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + TOKEN + '/', data);
    
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]